When to not use `incremental` tsconfig?
Where can I find official documentation that's explain why to not always use the incremental typescript tsconfig?

Have you looked at this? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#faster-subsequent-builds-with-the---incremental-flag

Yes, but I don't understand why not to always use the incremental. In which use case it's better to not use it?

Incremental compilation relies on cache files to speed up the build process. If you suspect that these cache files might be causing issues or if you want to avoid any potential stale state problems, you might prefer a full, clean build each time.
